# Encrypt ngModel value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption

I want to encrypt (using any algorithm) value of a `ngModel`. Only the `$modelValue` should be encrypted and view value should be plain text.

To do so, I came up with a small custom directive:-

```
angular.module('utilityModule').directive('encrypt', function() {
    var aesUtil = new AesUtil(128, 10);
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: false,
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            var modelName = tAttrs['ngModel'];
            var pattern = tAttrs['ngPattern']; // to check if there is ngPattern directive used.
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
                    // to avoid encrypting on every key press.
                    fn.$options = {
                        updateOn: 'blur'
                    };
                    fn.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                        //encrypt
                        console.log('parser invoked');
                        return value ? aesUtil.encrypt(modelName, modelName, modelName, value) : value;
                    });
                    fn.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                        //decrypt
                        console.log('formatter invoked');
                        return value ? aesUtil.decrypt(modelName, modelName, modelName, value) : value;
                    });
                    fn.$validators.pattern = function(){
                        // trying to overrule ngPattern directive. DOESN'T HELP!!
                        return true;
                    };
                    // Just for playing around
                    fn.$validators.amyValid = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                        console.log('Custom validator invoked. modelValue=' + modelValue + ' and viewValue=' + viewValue);
                        return true;
                    };
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {}
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The directive works except when we have ngPattern used alongwith the ngModel directive. For example:-

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-form="testForm">
        <input name="test" type="text" ng-model="test" encrypt ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"/>
        <br>
        {{test}}
    </div>
```

## My expectations:-

`ngPattern` directive should validate using the `$viewValue` instead of `$modelValue`.

How can I override the '`patternDirective`' directive present in core `angular.js`?

Or any other suggestions...

### UPDATE 1

Just realized that not just `ngPattern`, all other validations (maxLength, minLength, max, min) should be applied on view value only

### UPDATE 2

My debugger shows that the value passed to patternDirective validator is the encrypted one. Please see the attached screenshot.[image: encrypted value passed to patternDirective validator]

### UPDATE 3

Upgrading to angularjs 1.4.5 fixed the problem. I believe that 1.3.x has validation on model value and not view value.

Comment: typo possibly: `fn.$validators.amyValid`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0e001084ffff8674efad289d37cb16cc4e46b50a/src/ng/directive/validators.js >> pattern directive validates view value

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - Got it. But why then this is not working when I use ng-pattern ?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - Please see the UPDATE 2

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JSTIUI7cbyDMTqv3CIz0?p=preview everything worked as expected. Check one more time how you encrypt/decrypt

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - Not sure why I see encrypted string in ngPattern validator. Should angularjs version be the problem ? I am using "angular": "~1.3",

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - i think I will have to updgrade my angularjs version. In your plnkr changing angularjs version to 1.3.2 gives the error mention in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to angularjs 1.4.5 fixed the problem. I believe that 1.3.x has validation on model value and not view value.